# cannot GET objects from database Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i cannot get objects from my database. i'm getting nothing.
in terminal i'm not getting error and i'm entering on website without problem.
i want get information from .

```
 DT = Destination_Tour.objects.all()
```

my Views.py

```
def index(request):
min_date = f"{datetime.now().date().year}-{datetime.now().date().month}-{datetime.now().date().day}"
max_date = f"{datetime.now().date().year if (datetime.now().date().month+3)<=12 else datetime.now().date().year+1}-{(datetime.now().date().month + 3) if (datetime.now().date().month+3)<=12 else (datetime.now().date().month+3-12)}-{datetime.now().date().day}"
citynames = Place.objects.all()
slider = Slider.objects.all()
DT = Destination_Tour.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
    origin = request.POST.get('Origin')
    destination = request.POST.get('Destination')
    depart_date = request.POST.get('DepartDate')
    seat = request.POST.get('SeatClass')
    trip_type = request.POST.get('TripType')
    citynames = Place.objects.all()
    if(trip_type == '1'):
        return render(request, 'base.html', {
        'origin': origin,
        'destination': destination,
        'depart_date': depart_date,
        'seat': seat.lower(),
        'trip_type': trip_type,
        'name':citynames,
    })
else:
    return render(request, 'base.html', {
        'min_date': min_date,
        'max_date': max_date
    })
context = {
    'name':citynames,
    'sd': slider,
    'DT' : DT,
    }

return render(request,'base.html', context = context)
```

Comment: Did you try to get all data using django shell? type `python manage.py shell` and then import your model and type queryset `Destination_Tour.objects.all()`. Did it work?

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are `not passing your variable` in the proper place,

look closely, your index view got executed `before` you pass your `DT` variable via context

with `POST` and `GET` methods you can only `return` function two times, but you used it three times, and third time will `never be executed`

it should be like this:

```
def index(request):
    min_date = f"{datetime.now().date().year}-{datetime.now().date().month}-{datetime.now().date().day}"
    max_date = f"{datetime.now().date().year if (datetime.now().date().month+3)<=12 else datetime.now().date().year+1}-{(datetime.now().date().month + 3) if (datetime.now().date().month+3)<=12 else (datetime.now().date().month+3-12)}-{datetime.now().date().day}"
    citynames = Place.objects.all()
    slider = Slider.objects.all()
    DT = Destination_Tour.objects.all()

    #also good practice for debuging is to print your variables in terminal
    print(DT)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        origin = request.POST.get('Origin')
        destination = request.POST.get('Destination')
        depart_date = request.POST.get('DepartDate')
        seat = request.POST.get('SeatClass')
        trip_type = request.POST.get('TripType')
        citynames = Place.objects.all()
        if(trip_type == '1'):
            return render(request, 'base.html', {
            'origin': origin,
            'destination': destination,
            'depart_date': depart_date,
            'seat': seat.lower(),
            'trip_type': trip_type,
            'name':citynames,
            'DT' : DT,
        })
    else:
        return render(request, 'base.html', {
            'min_date': min_date,
            'max_date': max_date
            'DT' : DT,
        })
```